# Creating a sharepoint 2013 site collection with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to create a site collection and I get an message when opening the SP management shell console:

**"The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered"**

I have tried almost everything internet has to offer but no luck. It would be a great help if someone could share some ideas. I have used below site as a reference because it seems to be  the same issue.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2013/02/18/sharepoint-powershell-command-problem-featuredependencyid-are-not-registered.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.
Whenever, I load the PowerShell ISE and Type the command to load the SharePoint PowerShell module, it starts throwing error

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chjain/archive/2013/08/10/10440633.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! The problem was the user permissions. I had to use a different user with elevated permission to access the farm.